# MongoDB query for boolean. True, false or both

Tags: mongodb, vue.js

I'm building a MVEN project for a client, and coming from the FrontEnd world I'm new to MongoDB and have a basic question.

In my dashboard I have a list of task, with a boolean field called "isFinished" and I would like to filter my list to show all tasks, finished tasks or unfinished tasks with a select input.

this is my query in mongoose:

```
const tasks = await Task.find({ isFinished: req.query.isFinished }).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
```

It works fine when I have a value true or false in my select. But don't know how to show all tasks.

What value do I have to put in the select for show all tasks and what query in mongoose.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
const tasks = await Task.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
```

or you can do a request with a `$in` if you really want to filter on `isFinished`

```
const tasks = await Task.find({isFinished: {$in : [true, false]}}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use or to handle this

```
const tasks = await Task.find({
  $or: [
     { isFinished: true},
     { isFinished: false}
  ]
}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
```

however this fixes your problem but this way doesn't make sense! or It's not best practice.
better solution is to query all tasks and filter in client side

```
const tasks = await Task.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
let tasks_done = tasks.filter(task => task.isFinished)
let remaining_tasks = tasks.filter(task => !task.isFinished)
```